# Fancybox doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm getting an error on my website. When I try to close a frame of Fancybox plugin, it doens't close all. The screen is still locked.

On console debugging I can see this error `Object doesn't support property or method 'swing'`, in this line: `this.pos=f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]](this.state,c,0,1,i.duration)`

To see it online, click on some music link on http://www.justmp3.cn/baixar/david-guetta/

If someone has idea what should I do to solve my problem, I would thank too much!

Comment: In your script_result.js could you please comment "$("#fancybox-close")......." part and try again?there is something wrong with that part. I am saying this for debugging

Comment: Erik-try to update easing plugin.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error on your easing plugin.

Comment: @cubuzoa I removed that part "$("#fancybox-close").......", actually I added only to see if I get an alert when I click to close, but I didn't. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @coder The Easing plugin is already updated. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I think it should be some conflit between jQuery plugins, these same files were working in other website (a simple one), without other  jQuery plugins that I have in this new one.

Comment: @Erik-Try changing the order of the scripts as your easing is after pack.js try to move that front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your **easing** plugin.
try to get it from [here](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and include

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

I changed my JQuery Easing Plugin for this new one, but I have the same problem yet. It is really strange, I already spent more than 2 days trying everything, but I didn't find a succesful way.

Comment: I have updated and inlcluded more lines from other file and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To use "swing" effect it needs the easing plugin and you didn't add it so you should include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your_domain/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>
```

> Optional - Add transitions as jQuery by default supports only "swing"
>   and "linear"

**Reference:** [**fancybox**](http://fancybox.net/howto).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it already is declared. I tried different versions, but doesn't work.